# query in oracle to find multiple string patterns( contains 5-50 char) in a string in oracle

Tags: regex, oracle

i have almost 50 different string pattern that i need to look into a string and filter out the string that contains any one of those 50 string patterns
how can i write a query to to find those strings only that contain any one of these 50 string patterns.

```
 SELECT  STRING_1 FROM TABLE_1 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (UPPER(STRING_1),'((DBA)|ABC:|CDE,|QRT/)')
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and your desired output? Are those string patterns stored in a table or you are intending to hardcode them in your SQL(*which would be really ugly to do*)?

Comment: I have those string patterns in a table.

Comment: Ok, now you need to provide the sample data and your desired output as requested.

Answer (score 1):

```
SQL> 
with p (str) as  (
  select 'DBA' from dual union all 
  select 'ABC:' from dual union all 
  select 'CDE,' from dual union all 
  select 'QRT/' from dual union all
  select 'zzz:' from dual
)
, t (str) as (
  select 'test ABCDBAABC) ' from dual union all
  select 'AbC: xyz' from dual union all
  select 'MBC ' from dual union all
  select 'ABC ' from dual union all
  select 'ABC: and CDE, ' from dual union all
  select 'ZZZ:' from dual
)
select * from t join p
on ( upper(t.str) like '%' || upper(p.str) ||'%');

STR              STR 
---------------- ----
test ABCDBAABC)  DBA 
AbC: xyz         ABC:
ABC: and CDE,    ABC:
ABC: and CDE,    CDE,
ZZZ:             zzz:


SQL> 
with p (str) as  (
  select 'DBA' from dual union all 
  select 'ABC:' from dual union all 
  select 'CDE,' from dual union all 
  select 'QRT/' from dual union all
  select 'zzz:' from dual
)
, t (str) as (
  select 'test ABCDBAABC) ' from dual union all
  select 'AbC: xyz' from dual union all
  select 'MBC ' from dual union all
  select 'ABC ' from dual union all
  select 'ABC: and CDE, ' from dual union all
  select 'ZZZ:' from dual
)
select * from t join p
on (regexp_like(t.str, p.str, 'i'));

STR              STR 
---------------- ----
test ABCDBAABC)  DBA 
AbC: xyz         ABC:
ABC: and CDE,    ABC:
ABC: and CDE,    CDE,
ZZZ:             zzz:
```

store your patterns in a table. Join that with your table as shown. If it is possible to have more than one pattern in a value that needs to be checked, than it will be returned as many time the pattern occurs.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But does regexp_like will affect the performance?

Comment: It depends. If your base table is only a few thousand rows, you may not even notice anything as a lag. You may be able find that out yourself by testing both queries against your table.